# Matlab multidimensional correlation with circular data

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, correlation

I am kind of new to analyzing circular data and I have a quite complex problem.

I'm trying to correlate 2 multidimensional vectors (N observations x 2 dimensions) where one dimension is circular (i.e. angles in radians).

I have found the corr2 function for 2D correlations which seems to work fine (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html), I am however uncertain if I can use it on circular data (there isn't much information on it in the Matlab Documentation).

I found documentation on the Origin software which states that the correlations can be circular (http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/2D-Correlation) but I have no idea if it this generalizes to Malab.

I tried two approaches:

1- I input the linear and circular data as is:

```
r = corr2([Theta_X Amplitude_X], [Theta_Y Amplitude_Y]);
```

which yields very good results but I am unsure if they are valid.

2- I "linearized" the data by converting the polar coordinates into Cartesian (pol2cart):

```
r = corr2([x_X y_X], [x_Y y_Y]);
```

which yields noisier results.

My question is thus: can I use the corr2 function on circular data? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What happens if you convert amplitude and theta into a *complex* number, i.e., `Complex_X = Amplitude_X .* exp(1j * Theta_X)` and similarly `Complex_Y`? Does the plain old correlation between X and Y make more sense there? That might make sense if your amplitude/theta are measuring the same physical thing—if the two are totally unrelated physical phenomena, then maybe this approach isn’t suitable.

Comment: It seems to work by converting into complex numbers and taking the norm of the resulting complex vector (corr function) or the _r_ output of canonical correlations (canoncorr) directly (which yield the same result). 

Thank you very much for your help! I'll keep in mind using complex numbers in the future instead of 2D vectors.